# how to return different datatypes in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, xamarin

I have a method in C# that has to return 2 different objects based on input parameter.

How can that be done?

```
var nextPage = new LoadByContentType(1);
await App.Navigator.PushAsync(nextPage);

private ???? LoadByContentType(int Param1)
{
    if (Param1 == 1)
        return new ListPage(Param1);
    else
        return new WebviewPage(Param1);
}
```

Comment: Return common base type of both the types.

Comment: Thanks, your comment put me on the right track

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the common base type of both types (as @Sriram Sakthivel suggested) or use the base class for all other classes **`object`**:

> Supports all classes in the .NET Framework class hierarchy and provides low-level services to derived classes. This is the ultimate base class of all classes in the .NET Framework; it is the root of the type hierarchy.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

@ITGuy mentioned that `ContentPage` is the base class shared by both `ListPage` and `WebviewPage` so one working version of your code would be:

```
private ContentPage LoadByContentType(int Param1)
{
    if (Param1 == 1)
        return new ListPage(Param1);
    else
        return new WebviewPage(Param1);
}
```

Comment: Returning `object` doesn't really help in this scenario and can be really error-prone. The correct way is to use the common base class/interface/whatever.. Or maybe even use generics. `object` has its uses, but should be used carefully and avoided when possible.

Comment: Using object as a return type is the most easy way to shoot yourself in the foot, your answer is not incorrect per se, but you should stress about the use of a specific base class instead

Comment: I ended up using ContentPage, which is a base class shared by both ListPage and WebviewPage. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

You could create create a common class for the two object to inherit from with an enum for example to safely get the desired object.

```
public enum PageTypeEnum{ ListPage,WebviewPage};
public abstract class BasePage 
{
  //Common data..
  public abstract PagetTypeEnum PageType{get;}
} 
public class ListPage : BasePage
{
   public overide PageTypeENum PageType {get{return PageTypeEnum.ListPage;}}
}
public class WebviewPage: BasePage
{
   public overide PageTypeENum PageType {get{return PageTypeEnum.WebviewPage;}}
}
```

Usage:

```
private static BasePage LoadByContentType(int Param1)
{
    if (Param1 == 1)
        return new ListPage(Param1);
    else
        return new WebviewPage(Param1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use output parameters

```
private static BasePage LoadByContentType(int Param1, out int Param2, out int Param3)
{
   Param1 = 1;
   Param2 = 2;
   return something;
}
```

To call it you can do:

```
int int1, int2;
var something = LoadByContentType(1, out int1, out int2);
```

More information on C# out parameters are at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx